# Rails4 routing issue with old page in url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This is probably something small but I haven't gotten anywhere with googling it.

My routing file is like this (app/config/routes.rb)

```
.....
resources :apples
resources :oranges
```

When I go from a url like so, in the site
'root/orange/1/edit'
to 
'root/apple/new'

I'm getting 'orange/1/apple/new' instead of 'root/apple/new'

I think its either how I'm declaring the the route, or how I'm linking to it from the view. What do I need to check?

Update: Thanks. The problem was due to using a relative path. For anyone else running into this

I had in the view something like this

rather than

where in my route file there is
get 'fruit' => 'apples#new'
...
resources :apples

Hopefully that helps someone coming along after me.

Comment: Can you show your actual routes.rb code, properly formatted? It looks like you may be nesting the apple resource in the orange resource.

Comment: Could you post your view code? I think that would be helpful, it seems like a linking issue, but hard to tell. You can format your code with four indents and ` marks.

Comment: While it may not be the cause of the issue you've hit, in a standard Rails application, `resources` are pluralized (as are controllers with models in the singular). So `resources :apples` and `resources :oranges` are the convention (just FYI).

Comment: it wasn't nesting or the pluralized but thanks. Good to remember for the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you generating your link with the url helper?

`link_to new_apple_path`

It sounds like you are using a relative path, which would happen if you linked to 'apple/new' instead of '/apple/new', but really this should be handled for you if you are using the link helper rather than typing that path to links yourself.

If you have more question, please post your views code which is generating the link and the contents of your routes file.